# No internet connection inside Docker containers

Tags: networking, ubuntu, docker

I cannot execute any command requiring internet connection inside any Docker container.

Works:

```
docker run ubuntu /bin/echo 'Hello world'
```

Does not work:

```
docker run ubuntu apt-get update

Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
```

Similar with `pip` and `ping`.

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and not using firewall or corporate proxy server and have tried to restart Docker.

**Upd:**

Update in interactive mode fails in the same fashion.

```
docker exec -ti angry_goodall /bin/bash
apt-get update
#fails
ping google.com
#fails with "unknown host" message
ping 8.8.8.8 
# shows PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
# and than hangs indefinetly
```

`sudo apt-get update` runs successfully on host, i.e. on my computer outside docker.

**Upd** Docker version 1.12.1, build 23cf638

Comment: Can you ping a domain from the host? Can you run `apt-get update` while in interactive mode with the docker?

Comment: the output shows the error: Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com' ... try .. ping www.google.com .. see if you get the same response.. then try ... ping 8.8.8.8 ... if IP works, and host name doesn't then your DNS is broken (more /etc/resolv.conf to see what DNS server is being used)

Comment: @adampski, I updated question based on your suggestions.

Comment: @TG2, I updated question based on your suggestions as well.

Comment: What version of docker engine are you running?

Comment: @adampski, Docker version 1.12.1, build 23cf638

Comment: These might help you: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/866#issuecomment-19218300 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430371/my-docker-container-has-no-internet

Comment: Thank you, @adampski, for for the suggested solution. github.com/docker/docker/issues/866#issuecomment-19218300 helped. If you post it as answer I will mark it as best.

Comment: See this similar answer since the problem is about dns routing on docker https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35515203/docker-npm-install-error-getaddrinfo-enotfound-registry-npmjs-org-registry-npmj/49936357#49936357

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As suggested by [creack on GitHub issue #866 for Docker](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/866#issuecomment-19218300):

```
pkill docker
iptables -t nat -F
ifconfig docker0 down
brctl delbr docker0
docker -d
```

"It will force docker to recreate the bridge and reinit all the network rules"

Comment: I tried it, and this kills the network on my whole computer.

Comment: This is helpful and resolved the issue for me. Thank you.

Comment: The `-d` flag does not exit.

Comment: Hi @LuísdeSousa it's a shame you down voted this but consider the possibility that perhaps some switches are removed or altered in newer releases. Especially since this was over a year ago.

Comment: instead of only copy/past the command you could explain what these mean :)

Comment: On Linux, Docker manipulates iptables rules to provide network isolation. This is an implementation detail, and you should not modify the rules Docker inserts into your iptables policies.

Comment: This bug/problem still exists, even on CentOS 7 X86_64 with `docker 18.03.1-ce` installed from official docker repository on `CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)` with `3.10.0-862.3.2.el7.x86_64` kernel. Your answer helped me to solve this stupid bug! `docker -d` does not work anymore. I ran `systemctl start docker` instead.

Comment: For centos 7 you will need to install these `yum install net-tools bridge-utils` and start up docker again with `systemctl start docker` as already stated.

Comment: @adampski what is the current equivalent for `docker -d`?

Comment: you can also use `sudo docker network prune` after making sure all containers are down

Comment: for rocky linux 9, had to do following,
`sudo systemctl stop docker;
sudo iptables -t NAT -F;
sudo ip link set dev docker0 down;
sudo dnf install epel-release -y;
sudo dnf install -y bridge-utils;
sudo brctl delbr docker0;
sudo systemctl start docker;`

Comment: this worked for me. In ubuntu you can replace the last command with `sudo systemctl restart docker`

Answer (score 17):

When you create container using `docker run` without specifying it's network explicitly (`--network foo`), docker connects it to default `bridge` network.

Default `bridge` network has been deprecated (can't find information, from which version of Docker Engine), should be considered an implementation detail and shouldn't be used.

But, more importantly, any container connected to default `bridge` network prohibited from networking with outside world - see ["Differences between user-defined bridges and default bridge"](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge).

You can [enable such networking to outside world](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#enable-forwarding-from-docker-containers-to-the-outside-world), but I don't recommend to do so. It requires you to persist suggested host configuration changes, which can be not what you want.

Solution is simple: just *create* your own (user-defined) bridge network, name it, say, `common`, and use it explicitly with each one-off container created with `docker run`:

```
$ docker network create --driver bridge common
$ docker run -it --network common ubuntu:latest bash
```

Comment: this one is the answer, today

Comment: This is the simple and working solution

Comment: I can't believe docker keeps this secret so well hidden! One shouldn't have to dig to the fourth SO answer on the fifth page of Google results for a simple question like "get internet access in a container". The linked docs "differences between user-defined bridges and default bridge" do not actually say anything about external network access. The solution does work though; this should be the accepted answer. Is there a better reference?

Comment: Referenced docs no more saying anything about internet access from containers, but they did at the time of writing this answer. I don't have enough time (an will) to dig this problem again and update references, but if you already did that - feel free to edit answer.

Comment: Or just passing `--network host` without creating a new bridge network.

Comment: The whole "sales point" of docker is to isolate your services. Usage of `host` networking goes in opposite direction (except for most simplest cases, probably). Do we need to "isolate" one-off `docker run` containers? Although, docker ecosystem is not so good at managing networking stacks, I suppose.

Answer (score 12):

There is a similar issue at StackOverflow where [a different solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45644890/2066215) solves this issue with Docker 17.09 on Ubuntu 16.04:

Check the contents of `resolv.conf`:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

If it includes a line like `nameserver 127.0.1.1` it means the containers are obtaining an incorrect names server. To fix this edit the `NetworkManager.conf` file:

```
$ sudo pico /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

And comment out the line with `dns=dnsmasq`; the file should look like this:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
#dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

Finally, restart the network manager:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

Test again the container:

```
$ docker run ubuntu:16.04 apt-get update
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]
```

Comment: My install matched the description and the above approach resolved the issue for me.

Comment: updated answer for Ubuntu 18.04: https://superuser.com/a/1335054

Answer (score 9):

I've already answered it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45644890/

I'm copying the answer below:

> First thing to check is run `cat /etc/resolv.conf` in the **docker container**. If it has an invalid DNS server, such as `nameserver 127.0.x.x`, then the container will not be able to resolve the domain names into ip addresses, so `ping google.com` will fail.
>
> Second thing to check is run `cat /etc/resolv.conf` on the **host machine**. Docker basically copies the host's `/etc/resolv.conf` to the container everytime a container is started. So if the host's `/etc/resolv.conf` is wrong, then so will the docker container.
>
> If you have found that the host's `/etc/resolv.conf` is wrong, then you have 2 options:
>
> 1. Hardcode the DNS server in daemon.json. This is easy, but not ideal if you expect the DNS server to change.
> 2. Fix the hosts's `/etc/resolv.conf`. This is a little trickier, but it is generated dynamically, and you are not hardcoding the DNS
>    server.
>
> ---
>
> **1. Hardcode DNS server in docker daemon.json**
>
> - Edit `/etc/docker/daemon.json`
>
>   ```
>    {
>        "dns": ["10.1.2.3", "8.8.8.8"]
>    }  * Restart the docker daemon for those changes to take effect:      `sudo systemctl restart docker`
>   ```
> - Now when you run/start a container, docker will populate
>   `/etc/resolv.conf` with the values from `daemon.json`.
>
> ---
>
> **2. Fix the hosts's `/etc/resolv.conf`**
>
> **A. Ubuntu 16.04 and earlier**
>
> - For Ubuntu 16.04 and earlier, `/etc/resolv.conf` was dynamically generated by NetworkManager.
> - Comment out the line `dns=dnsmasq` (with a `#`) in   `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`
> - Restart the NetworkManager to regenerate `/etc/resolv.conf` :   `sudo systemctl restart network-manager`
> - Verify on the host: `cat /etc/resolv.conf`
>
> **B. Ubuntu 18.04 and later**
>
> - Ubuntu 18.04 changed to use [`systemd-resolved` to generate `/etc/resolv.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/systemd-resolved.service.8.html#contenttoc3). Now by default it uses a local DNS cache
>   127.0.0.53. That will not work inside a container, so Docker will default to Google's 8.8.8.8 DNS server, which may break for people
>   behind a firewall.
> - `/etc/resolv.conf` is actually a symlink (`ls -l /etc/resolv.conf`) which points to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` (127.0.0.53)
>   by default in Ubuntu 18.04.
> - Just change the symlink to point to `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`, which lists the real DNS servers:
>   `sudo ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`
> - Verify on the host: `cat /etc/resolv.conf`
>
> Now you should have a valid `/etc/resolv.conf` on the host for docker
> to copy into the containers.

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work

Comment: "Hardcode DNS server in docker daemon.json" worked

Comment: Hardcoding in daemon.json works for me. However, it seems better use `8.8.8.8` as primary DNS since it's much faster (in my experience)

Answer (score 1):

For me, this seemed to do the trick:

`systemctl stop docker`

`systemctl start docker`

(probably `systemctl restart docker` would have also worked)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had docker installed via `snap`, after removing it and installing by following instructions from the [official website](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) it started to work normally.