# Docker containers cannot connect to internet in Fedora 32?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, docker, docker-compose

## The Problem

I have recently created a docker container that has to pull a public github repository, however, it isn't able to resolve the host github.com. In fact, it isn't able to even execute ping command.

**NOTE: all network operations here are inside the container after building, when the container runs**

`ping www.google.com` gives `cannot resolve host`

It cannot connect to the internet at all.

After looking on the internet and [Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#ip-forwarding-problems)

## Solutions Tried

### 1) Enabling IP Forwarding as given in [Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#ip-forwarding-problems)

I tried enabling IPForwarding but to no avail.

Contents of `/usr/lib/systemd/network/80-container-host0.network` after enabling IPForwarding

```
...
[Network]
DHCP=yes
LinkLocalAddressing=yes
LLDP=yes
EmitLLDP=customer-bridge
IPForward=true // this line was changed
[DHCP]
UseTimezone=yes
```

### 2) Recreating Docker Bridge as given in [Stack Overflow](https://superuser.com/a/1130993/1214210)

```
pkill docker
iptables -t nat -F
ifconfig docker0 down
brctl delbr docker0
sudo service restart docker
```

This was originally effective in [this issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/866#issuecomment-19218300)

There is a solution for ubuntu, but my network configuration doesn't have that [problematic](https://superuser.com/a/1274161/1214210) line

my `sudo pico /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` is just filled with comments

```
[main]
#plugins=ifcfg-rh


[logging]
#level=TRACE
#domains=ALL
```

### 3) Installing IP-Tables service [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60074328/2851473)

```
sudo yum install iptables-services
sudo service docker restart
```

### 4) Overriding DNS configuration in docker-compose-[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41717180/docker-compose-container-using-host-dns-server)

```
version: "3.3"
services:
    airflow:
        build: 
            context: ./airflow
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports: 
            - 8080:8080
        environment: 
            GITHUB_DAG_REPO: https://github.com/siddharths067/HelloAirflow.git
        dns:
            - 8.8.8.8
            - 8.8.4.4
```

## The Docker Network Inspect of the Image's Network

I don't know if this would be of any use

```
docker network inspect airflowsetup_default 
[
    {
        "Name": "airflowsetup_default",
        "Id": "141a518c1440e603f75774c54f42de33e9173e3f062a0a0bc772db13a7f1ef5d",
        "Created": "2020-08-30T14:42:30.951975699+05:30",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "airflowsetup",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.25.4"
        }
    }
]
```

#### Output

```
airflow_1  | GITHUB DAG REPO IS
airflow_1  | https://github.com/siddharths067/HelloAirflow.git
airflow_1  | Cloning into 'HelloAirflow'...
airflow_1  | fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/siddharths067/HelloAirflow.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com
```

Comment: check my answer for the most likely root cause of your problem and a possible solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Event though the OP found a workaround for his problem and closed this issue, he did not find the root issue. The fact that Docker's default bridged network `bridge` is connected to the internet and `airflowsetup_default` is not suggests that something is wrong with Docker networking setup.

I did some research and it turns Fedora 32 decided it doesn't really care if Docker works on it or not.

It's not even possible to install Docker in a way described in the documentation and if you install the package provided by Fedora it still doesn't work correctly - more information on that issue can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1021293/docker-ce-not-available-for-fedora-32), [here](https://fedoramagazine.org/docker-and-fedora-32/) and [here](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/955).

The main issue is that there is no internet connectivity inside the containers if they are connected to any custom bridged network - whether it was created using `docker network create` or by docker-compose.

The reason why is simple - Docker assumes that the firewall used by the OS is [iptables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables), but Fedora 32 uses [firewalld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewalld) by default. That means Docker cannot configure the firewall manually - it has to be configured by hand.

For reference purposes I will first describe how to set up Docker on a clean Fedora 32 installation.

First run the following commands:

```
sudo grubby --update-kernel=ALL --args="systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0"
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

This will configure cgroups to be compatible with Docker daemon and allow your user to use Docker CLI without sudo.

Next restart your system to apply changes and run:

```
sudo dnf install -y moby-engine docker-compose nano
sudo systemctl enable docker
sudo systemctl start docker
```

to install and enable Docker.

Now go to the directory that contains your `docker-compose.yml` and run `docker-compose up -d`. Yuo should see `docker-compose` creating a network for you and then creating the container. If your container requires internet connection on startup (like the OP's) it will fail to start.

Now run `sudo iptables-save | grep DOCKER` and you should see something like:

```
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -o br-b56fa303f315 -j DOCKER
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-b56fa303f315 ! -o br-b56fa303f315 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-b56fa303f315 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -i br-b56fa303f315 -j RETURN
```

`docker0` is Docker's default bridged network, while `br-b56fa303f315` is the new network created by `docker-compose` (yours may have a different name). If your OS were using `iptables` everything would work as expected, but it does not, so we need to check the configuration of `docker0` in `firewalld`.

Run `firewall-cmd --get-active-zones` and you'll get something similar to:

```
docker
  interfaces: docker0
public
  interfaces: eth0 eth1
```

You can see that `bridge` network is in `docker` zone, but the new network is not. In fact it's not listed at all, which means it's in the default zone. You can check what that is by running `firewall-cmd --get-default-zone`. On a clean install of Fedora 32 it's `public`.

So run (remember to replace `br-b56fa303f315` with your interface name):

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=docker --add-interface=br-b56fa303f315
```

run `docker-compose up -d` if your service failed to start previously and voila - your container has network connectivity.

Unfortunately if your restart your system it'll lose that connectivity again.

You can prevent that by using:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=docker --add-interface=br-b56fa303f315
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

However if you create any new networks or recreate existing ones (for example by running `docker-compose down` and then `docker-compose up -d` again) you'll have to repeat the process.

So what is the solution to this problem?

First, write down all network interfaces that are currently attached to the default zone - in this example `eth0` and `eth1`.

Then run the following (replacing `public` with your default zone's name)

```
sudo firewall-cmd --set-default-zone=docker
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-interface=eth0
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-interface=eth1
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Now the interfaces that were previously in your default zone should be there again, but all the new interfaces (and therefore all the new Docker networks) will be automatically added to `docker` zone, which will give them full network connectivity.

Comment: Holy Shit, no wonder why I wasn't able to figure it out. This is too complex for me to figure it out on my own. Can I install iptables in fedora? would that work?

Comment: It’s not that simple. I didn’t want to confuse the issue even more in my answer, but in Linux firewall was always a part of the kernel. First it was `ipfirewall`, then `ipchains`, then `iptables` and now `nftables`. Other “firewalls”, including `firewalld`,  are merely frontends that make managing them easier. You can read the reasons why Docker used to work with `firewalld` in Fedora 31, but not 32 here: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/firewalld_default_to_nftables

Comment: I think setting the default zone to `docker` is the best solution, but you may also try forcing `firewalld` to use `iptables` as described here: https://dev.to/ozorest/fedora-32-how-to-solve-docker-internal-network-issue-22me

Comment: When I fetch active zones I don't even get `public` interfaces https://pastebin.pl/view/7cf674b7

Comment: The output of that command depends on your current system configuration. It's possible that you have no interfaces in `public` zone. Check what zones you do have: `firewall-cmd --get-zones`. If there's one named `docker`, you can still do `sudo firewall-cmd --set-default-zone=docker` to fix Docker networks. Otherwise `sudo firewall-cmd --set-default-zone=trusted` should work, but will make your system less secure.

Answer (score 2):

I followed an alternative solution [from the Fedora Magazine](https://fedoramagazine.org/docker-and-fedora-32/):

> Whitelist docker in firewall
>
> To allow Docker to have network access, two commands are needed.
>
> ```
> sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-interface=docker0
> sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=FedoraWorkstation
> --add-masquerade
> ```
>
> The first command will add the Docker-interface to the trusted
> environment which allows Docker to make remote connections. The second
> command will allow docker to make local connections. This is
> particularly useful when multiple Docker containers are in as a
> development environment.

Then you should run this command to validate the changes

```
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Normally, you don't have to reboot your computer and your next containers are going to be connected.

In case, it does not work, you could try to:

1. First, restart a new container
2. Second, restart docker: `sudo systemctl restart docker`
3. Finally, reboot your computer

Comment: That did the trick here (Fedora 33).

Answer (score 0):

Adding `network-mode: bridge` to my docker-compose file seems to work. But I feel this might not be the proper way to do this. I shouldn't have to over-ride anything to allow my containers to connect.

```
version: "3.3"
services:
    airflow:
        build: 
            context: ./airflow
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports: 
            - 8080:8080
        environment: 
            GITHUB_DAG_REPO: https://github.com/siddharths067/HelloAirflow.git
        # dns:
        #     - 8.8.8.8
        #     - 8.8.4.4
        network_mode: bridge
```

Comment: This is strange - as far as I know setting `network_mode` to `bridge` forces the container to connect to default Docker bridged network rather than to the project-specific bridged network created by default by docker-compose. Did you use top-level `networks` key to customize that project-specific network? Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: I will be honest, I don't understand what you said. I just searched over internet for docker files and used this setting :(

Comment: I meant that when you specify `network_mode: bridge`, you are connecting your container to a network called `bridge` - which was created during Docker installation - rather than to network `airflowsetup_default` - which is created by docker-compose.